# Can you patent in a futuristic idea with great detail

Tags: patentability, prior-art, patent-lifetime, provisional

Like a space industry idea for AI are in an immortality idea etc using a pre vision patent and a great detail but not a physical product yet then license it to companies are super AI concepts or idea it's in great detail but can we license to a company to build the future

Comment: What do you mean by “pre vision”?

Comment: Could you perhaps edit the question to be clearer? We don't know quite what you mean by "immortality idea" or "pre vision"?

Answer (score 2):

It depends, as George White explains, on whether the invention is sufficiently enabled. It is possible to get a patent on an invention that isn't realizable with current technology or where it is economically infeasible. [Peter Glaser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Glaser) obtained a patent on the [solar power satellite](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/1e/be/9d/f12e68e86660ea/US3781647.pdf) in 1973. There was no hope for actual implementation of his invention before the patent expired in 1990. It did gain him significant notoriety, however.

Answer (score 1):

From the wording of your question I would say *no*.

To get a patent one must have a fixed idea of how to make and use the invention. And the written specification and drawings need to show someone of ordinary skill in the art how to make and use the invention without undue experimentation. As your question is worded I do not think you know how to make anything you mentioned actually work.

To get a patent you do not need a polished, production ready, efficient design. But it can’t just be blue sky.  If “great detail” means you have actually figured it out, then you can get a patent without a working model as long as your design does not involve violations of any known law of physics.

If you actually invent teleportation you can get a patent. If think just think teleportation would be cool you can’t get a patent.